# Como obter os dados de uma pagina especifica na web?

Tags: javascript, python, json

Tenho como objetivo criar um script que obtenha dados como bugs,issues entre outros  da seguinte pagina do [Spring Framework](https://jira.spring.io/browse/spr/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel), infelizmente não tenho nenhum código para mostrar pois de fato não faço muita ideia de como obter esses dados.

A duvida e: Como obter os dados mostrados na pagina e gerar um arquivo json com os mesmos? de preferencia utilizando python ou javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria melhor você entrar em contato com o site e pedir acesso a alguma API para conseguir esses dados.
Usar um "parser" no site deles, pode gerar muitos requests, assim eles podem bloquear o acesso para o seu IP. Mas se tiver que ser assim, em python pode usar a biblioteca [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).
Um exemplo bem simples:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

fp = urllib.request.urlopen(
    "https://jira.spring.io/browse/spr/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel")
html = fp.read().decode("utf8")
fp.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find(id='fragstatussummary')
nome = table.h3
print(nome.contents[0])
for linha in table.find_all('tr'):
    name = linha.a
    count = linha.find('td', class_='cell-type-collapsed')
    if name:
        print('{}: {}'.format(name.contents[0], count.contents[0]))
```

Resultado:
    Status Summary
    Open: 1542
    In Progress: 12
    Reopened: 49
    Resolved: 4740
    Closed: 9299
    Waiting for Feedback: 45
    Investigating: 56